# image pull fails with x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: podman

I stumbled across podman today and decided trial it as a replacement for docker desktop. It all looks good, I have used kind to setup a k8s dev cluster, except that images aren't pulled unless I add the flag ' --tls-verify=false'.

I am running on a mackbook pro with the M1 chip.

The error:

```bash
podman pull image nginx:latest                  
Resolving "image" using unqualified-search registries (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/image:latest...
Resolving "nginx" using unqualified-search registries (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/nginx:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://image:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error: initializing source docker://nginx:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf?

Comment: ls -la /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf
ls: /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: I have reinstalled podman and are now getting a different error message which --tls-verify=false bypasses

```bash
Error: initializing source docker://image:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/image: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required


Error: copying system image from manifest list: parsing image configuration: Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/1d/???/data?verify=???": dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com: i/o timeout